# How to replace straight quotes with curly quotes in pasted text

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using Word 2007 SP3. The autoformat option, "Change straight quotes to curly quotes" is turned on. If I type text into Word directly, then straight quotes are converted correctly into curly quotes, also known as smart quotes. However, if I select text that contains straight quotes and paste that text into Word, the text is pasted with straight quotes. How do I replace the straight quotes in the pasted text with curly quotes?

Answer (score 5):

There’s a great solution:

If you **Find & Replace a quote character with itself**, Word will re-apply the smart quote settings.

1. Open the *Replace* window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>)
2. Type "single quote" / apostrophe (<kbd>'</kbd>) in the find field
3. Type the **same character** in the replace field
4. Click "Replace All" <sub><sup>(Or one at a time if you prefer)</sup></sub>
5. Repeat steps 2–4 with "double quote" (<kbd>"</kbd>)

All quote marks in the document now have smart-quote applied.

[image]

---

I would never have guessed this, many thanks to the site that shared the answer: https://www.editing-writing.com/mass-change-straight-quotes-smart-quotes-word-document/

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I found.

1. Turn the option "Replace straight quotes with curly quotes" on.
2. Paste the text that includes straight quotes. The text appears with the straight quotes.
3. Edit, Replace, " with "
4. The text now includes curly quotes in place of straight quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this isn't the finest/best solution, but this could work:

- Replace `"<` (straight quotes before the beginning of a word) by `“` (opening curly quotes)
- Replace `>"`  (straight quotes after the end of a word) by `”` (closing curly quotes)

Remember that the replacing menu can be opened with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, and that you need to enable there the *"Use wildcards"* option.

More info on wildcards and what's happening here can be found in Microsoft Office's [help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-or-other-items-50b45f26-c4b8-4003-b9e4-315a3547f69c#bm8).

Comment: That's very helpful and may well do everything I want. Thank you!

Comment: @KenJohnson Give it a try, and if it works, let us know by accepting the answer! :)